# Ruby on Rails: 2nd button in form does not submit form fields to params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with my ruby on rails 3 form_tag. It used to work just fine. Now I realized I need a second submit button (named "Select Standard"). The button works fine, calls the right controller method and so on. For some reason though the inputs of the form don't get passed to the params[] hash. Any ideas why?

Example below (used to be working) with the 2nd button:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Select energies for evaluation </legend>
<%= form_tag ge_insert_energies_url(:id => @m.id) do %>
 <p>
     <table border = "solid">
     <tr>
        <th> Isotope </th>
        <th> Energy [keV]</th>
     </tr>
         <% @isos.each_with_index do |iso,i| %>
            <% unless @glines[i]=="blank" %>
                 <% @glines[i].each do |line| %>
                     <tr>
                         <% if line == @glines[i].first %>
                             <td rowspan="<%=@glines[i].count%>"> <%= iso.isotope %></td>
                         <% end %>
                         <td> <%= line.energy %> </td>
                         <td><%=check_box_tag "energies[select][]",line.id,@data.in    clude?(line.id)%>
                     </tr>
                 <% end %>
             <% end %>
         <% end %>
     </table>
 </p>

 <p><div style = "float:left; width:auto"> 
     <%= button_to "Submit", ge_insert_energies_url(:id => @m.id), :confirm => "Are     you sure? Data from deselected lines will be deleted." %></div>
     <%= button_to "Select Standard", ge_insert_energies_url(:id=>@m.id, :standard     => true) , :confirm => "Are you sure? Data from deselected lines will be deleted."%>
 </p>
 <% end %>


</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes: 
 ***- if you are using form_tag then the submission should be initiated by submit_tag not by button_to, so I suggest to keep the action part in form_tag ONLY not in submit_tag/button_to.***

Here I am posting solution to your issue (for simplicity i have just kept 2 fields):

```
<%= form_tag hold_value_visits_path(id: @visit.id) do %>

    <div>
        <%= label_tag 'first Name' %>
        <%= text_field_tag  :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= label_tag 'last Name' %>
        <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div> 
         <%= hidden_field_tag :standard, false %>
    </div>

     <p>
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', id: 'simple_submit %>
        <%= submit_tag "Second Submit', id: 'second_submit'  %>
     </p>

 <% end %>
```

With your second submit you want to pass standard value to be TRUE. 
check the hidden_field I have added whose default value is false.

```
//on click of the second_submit you want it to be true. 
    $('#second_submit').on('cick', function(){
       $('#standard_hidden').val(true);
    });
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I realized I don't actually need the data, just the info if the 'other' button was pressed.